# Question about search queries in Twitter if I have some conditional arguments

Tags: search, twitter

I want to search in twitter by this conditional query

Search for tweets that contains both #hash1 #hash2 OR just contains #hash3

> > (#hash1 AND hash2) OR #hash3

I tried this

## hash1 #hash2 OR #hash3

but it only shows the 1st arguments's result..

How ganna I write that in the search query ?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's Search API does not support using parentheses like that.

http://search.twitter.com/operators